# Angular2+ How can I switch locale at runtime?

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization

I have looked at the i18n stuff in Angular2+ and I really like it. However, my requirement is to allow the user to select their language at runtime.

In some cases more than one person will be using the same terminal so it will be necessary to switch languages at different points in the day, or perhaps even during a task (English manager handing control over to a non-English worker to complete some input).

Is there a way to do this in Angular2+ (currently using Angular 4) or will I need to roll my own solution?

Comment: Would it be a solution for you to build your app multiple times - once for each language? Then have it on a server in /en /fr /de folders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need some i18n libraries.

Like [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) or [angular-l10n](https://github.com/robisim74/angular-l10n)

I suggest **ngx-translate**.